# Language Module

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise, language-package

So I kinda try to understand it's purpose, but I fail to do that.
I made a sample module.

```
app/i18n/Lang/en_KR
```

language.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>en_KR</code>
    <vendor>lang</vendor>
    <package>en_KR</package>
</language>
```

registration.php

```
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE, 'lang_en_kr', __DIR__);
```

composer.json

```
{
  "name": "lang/language-en_kr",
  "description": "Eng to Korea",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "102.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  },
  "version": "100.3.3"
}
```

And what now ?

As I went to the Admin Panel of my StoreView

```
System -> Configuration -> Main Webiste -> My store view -> General
```

And right now what I would expect is that my new language (en_KR) would be existing, in the locale, but it does not, am I missing something, and the purpose of the packs is kinda different ??

When I made a record in core_config_data to my store and set the value of:

```
|      path          | value|
-----------------------------
|general/locale/code | en_CR|
```

and now I added a file in any module under

VENDOR/MODULE/i18n/en_CR.csv
And the value was populated.

What's the purpose of this magic thing has anyone idea??
Am I'm miss understanding it's purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below link

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/270

its very useful to create language pack

Comment: I think you did not understand my question,  I did not ask for a tutorial  as my lang is set or at least it's listed by the ComponentRegistrar,  and this tutorial leads to installing some kind of external extension